# Hide Menu items base on capability

Tags: menus, user-roles

What is the best way to add/remove items for the `wp_nav_menu()` based on user roles?

For instance a custom menu that looks like:

- Some Page
- Some Other Page
- Special Admin Page

Where the `Special Admin Page` should only be visible for admin users.

Is this best done with `wp_nav_menu_items` filter or do I need a custom Walker?

This is a possible duplicate of: [Hide menu items for visitors and filter based on role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36335/hide-menu-items-for-visitors-and-filter-based-on-role) but that doesn't appear to have been completely solved.  Though it does mention a [tutorial about a custom Walker](http://www.tomauger.com/2011/web-development/wordpress/wordpress-hiding-menu-items-from-users-based-on-their-roles-using-a-custom-walker) that seems relevant.

**EDIT:**

Based on Toscho's answer and [How to add a custom field in the advanced menu properties?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/how-to-add-a-custom-field-in-the-advanced-menu-properties) I combined the two to form my own plugin

[Nav Menu Roles](https://github.com/helgatheviking/Nav-Menu-Roles)

Fair warning that I cannot vouch for its speed and I am relatively certain that it will not work *with* another custom Walker, but it was a one-day plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039). Redefine the method `start_el()` only:

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args )
{
    if ( 'Your secret item title' !== $item->title 
        or current_user_can( 'administrator' ) 
    )
    {
        parent::start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Please mind that this is just pseudo code. I can not give it a test at the moment.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I don't think you can pass a role name to `current_user_can()` though.  I wish you could though.  On another note is there a way to add some checkboxes to the advanced menu options (along w/ description, etc)?  Doesn't look like it, but if there was I could wrap this into a plugin.

Comment: `current_user_can()` accepts role names too, it is just poorly named. And no, there is still no hook to add more fields to menu items. JavaScript might be an option to insert those.

Comment: Gotcha.  It is marked in the codex as not working perfectly with role name, which is why I thought that.  Can I rely on Javascript?  Ie, the menu drag and drop already does rely on Javascript so I can assume that most customizing the menu will have Javascript running?

Comment: No, you cannot. :) Menus can be created and edited without JavaScript.

Comment: I did find this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/how-to-add-a-custom-field-in-the-advanced-menu-properties which is pretty close.